# Problema con contraseña SA Sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, contraseña

El problemas es que necesito entra con el usuario SA pero ya intente de todo:

- No puedo cambiar la contraseña que me pide permisos de sysadmin
- No puedo entrar con autentificacion de windows por que no tengo cuenta hay y para crearla igual necesito ser SA
- Intente por **CMD** pero igual al llegar a cierto puento me dice que no tengo acceso
- Con el comando *-m* tampoco me deja solo tengo una cuenta que es de **SQL server** autentificacion
- Intente crear un nuevo usuario pero tampoco me deja

Necesito ayuda! gracias.

Comment: Que error te da cuando intentas autenticarte en el server?

Comment: Y si inicias la BD en single-user mode? Ahí debería permitirte restablecer la contraseña

Comment: Tambien lo hice pero al momento de ingresar me dice que el usuario que estoy utilizando no tiene privilegios para entrar

Comment: @CamiloBernal si puedo entrar con una cuenta que tengo pero esa cuenta solo tiene privilegos para ver y modificar una base de datos no a los usuarios

Comment: Si no estás en el rol sysadmin o no tienes acceso a la misma cuenta SA, será imposible cambiar nada de dicha cuenta.

Comment: Es lo que quiero saber no hay nadie con el rol sysadmin mas que el Sa pero no me se la contraseña

Answer (score 0):

> No puedo entrar con autentificacion de windows por que no tengo cuenta hay y para crearla igual necesito ser SA

No tienes que ser SA para crear una cuenta de windows. Si eres administrador local de windows, y sigues al dedillo lo comentado en esta nota proporcionada por Microsoft, podrás disponer del servidor. Ahora bien sino eres SysAdmin, no eres Administrador de Windows, yo diría que se llama hackear, y me da la impresión de que eso será bastante más difícil.

[Reiniciar Sql Server con cuenta Administrador Local](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/connect-to-sql-server-when-system-administrators-are-locked-out?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Y en caso de no ser administrador tendria que pedirle al administrador oficial que entre al Misrosoft Sql para que el modifique las contraseñas??

Comment: No un administrador local, puede reiniciar el servicio sql con la opción M, como te muestra el link de Microsoft. Luego del reinicio, puede generar un nuevo usuario con privilegios sysAdmin, o simplemente cambiar la contraseña de la cuenta del sa.

Comment: Realize lo del documento que enviaste pero despues del paso 8 me dice "Conectar con el Explorador de objetos mediante la autenticación de Windows" pero al hacer esto me sale un error:18456 y esto pasa igual con el inciso b y c o no se si este haciendo algo mal?

Comment: En el log de errores, de la carpeta C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQLXX.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Log donde xx es la versión, dispones de archivos de log. ErrorLoG

Comment: Edita ese log y busca el error que indicas, y pega el contenido completo aquí, o mira realmente, porque el estado del error te dice exactamente el porque: https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/mssqlserver-18456-database-engine-error?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: 2019-12-18 10:03:43.42 Logon       Error: 18456, gravedad: 14, estado: 5.
2019-12-18 10:03:43.42 Logon       Login failed for user 'FCA\victor.martinez'. Motivo: no se encontró un inicio de sesión que coincida con el nombre proporcionado. [CLIENTE: <local machine>]

Comment: A esto te refieres?

Comment: Si explicitamente a eso. Según lo que dice el Sql, FCA\victor martinez no pertenece al grupo local de administradores del equipo. Pero fíjate bien que en la página de Microsoft menciona explicitamente, en el punto 8, que se pueden producir un error en varias conexiones.